# Is there any component such EditText in Android Xamarin with C# for infinite text?

Tags: c#, android, xml, visual-studio, xamarin

I am doing a text editor in Android and I am currently working in an Android APP (Xamarin) developed in C#.

My problem is in the XML I am defining a component with a EditText multiline but the issue is that it is a fixed component but I want to be dynamic. It means I want this component to be scrolled infinitely by the right hand side and down while the user write and go down. Because now when I end writing in one line automatically go to the other and I do not want this, I want do keep writing in the same line.

My XML is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />
    <EditText
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/message"
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:gravity="top|left"
        android:textColor="@color/textcolor"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Kind regards.

Comment: To keep writing on the same line, this feature is avaiable for the single-line `EditTect`. You could set the `android:inputType` to **text** or set `android:singleLine` to **true** for that.

Comment: I have tried with android:inputType="textMultiLine", android:inputType="text|textMultiLine" and android:inputType="text" with the property android:singleLine to true without the result I want, it keeps writiing in the same line but there is no jump of line.

Comment: Do you mean that it's able to keep writing in one line and choose to switch to the next line as you wish?

Comment: Yes, like notepad++ you are writing in a single line at the beggining but the component is scaling while you are writing in the same line, but if you press Enter you go to the second line.

Comment: So which component or properties of the XML should I use in order to do this feature?

Comment: I've posted a answer to describe the method code, you could check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the **inputType** to **textMultiLine** in layout.xml.

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit_text"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Then set **HorizontallyScrolling** to true which will allow the text content to be wider than the view in code behind.

Activity class

```
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.layout1);

        FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.edit_text).SetHorizontallyScrolling(true);
    }
}
```

[image]